# Printing failure message in a try else block

Tags: specman, e

I have a code block like this.

```
try {
   gen <object> keeping { <constraints>};
} else {
   error(Failed to generate){
      out(<additional debug information>);
   };
};
```

I would like to have Specman print out the regular debug message from a gen failure along with my additional debug information. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "regular debug message" you mean the message generated by Specman when encountering a generation failure, then no, you can't print this message and your own custom message. This is the whole point of a `try` block, to eat up any errors and to replace them with a custom response.

Comment: That's too bad. I figured this might be the case.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know more about this, you might want to check out the reflection classes `rf_constraint` and `rf_constraint_layer`. You can use them to see whether a constraint is satisfied before you actually do generation (and possibly get an error).

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think it solves my problem.
Looking into this, it seems that reflection will only tell me if a particular constraint to satisfied on an already generated struct (and then modified I assume). Doesn't seem like it matches what I need